# python memap or pybuffer for large image processing

Tags: python, c++, numpy, word-wrap

I want to write a python wrapper for a c++ library. The part I want is a c++ image object to a numpy array. My intial thought was to create a `PyBuffer` using Python C API and with SWIG generate bindings. `numpy.frombuffer` can then handle the pybuffer which actually holds the image. So far so good. But when I read about `python.memap` things changed and I want to know wheather its good choice to use `python.memap` C object instead of `PyBuffer` object?

What will be the pros and cons here?. Images handled by c++ library will could be very large. ~4GB for one example.

Comment: You could use SWIG & ``numpy.i`` to create a memory view of your C++ data. Con: You'll get segmentation faults, if you're not careful. Pro: No duplicating of the data, no messing around with ``PyBuffer``. Check http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/SWIG_NumPy_examples#head-74ef8f02201f64b0bb6be71140f696216cfcd5be for a simple example.

Comment: @Dietrich, Indeed it was helpful and I will definetley give a try with it. Could you explain also why memap was not in this picture or maybe I am missing something very simple. I dont know. In any case i will not be messing with PyBuffer.

Comment: I never really needed to care how the wrapping in ``numpy.i`` is done, since it is all abstracted away. I.e., you get an Numpy Array object as a return value, when calling an appropriately wrapped C++ function. Browsing through ``numpy.i``, it seems that the Numpy C-Arrays are accessed directly.

Comment: @Dietrich, Still I didnt get the link properly with Numpy C-Array and memap in Python.

Comment: @Dietrich, could you expand your first comment as answer and I can accept it and mark is closed!.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - had some busy days. As far I understand SWIG, memap is not used. If it is used, it is hidden in the wrapper code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As requested, a minimal example according to [SciPy' Cookbook](http://wiki.scipy.org/Cookbook/SWIG_NumPy_examples#head-74ef8f02201f64b0bb6be71140f696216cfcd5be):

The file `tst.i` is the SWIG Interface file, which already has the C++ code for allocating dynamically 100 `doubles`. Also a function to print the array contents to `stdout` is implemented:

```
%module(docstring="A Simple Numpy Memview example") tstI

%{ 
   #define SWIG_FILE_WITH_INIT
  // Her comes the C-code:
  #include<iostream>
  double *x = NULL;
  void __call_at_begining() {
    std::cout <<  "__call_at_begining() ..." << std::endl; 
    x = new double(100);
    for(int i=0; i<100;i++) // fill x with some values
      x[i] = i*10;
  } 
  void __call_at_end(void) {
    std::cout <<  "__call_at_end() ..." << std::endl; 
    if (x != NULL) 
      free(x);
  }

  // The interface for the memory view:
  void view_x(double** d, int* d_n) {
    *d = x;
    *d_n = 100;
  }
  // dump context to stdout:
  void print_x() {
    std::cout << "x = ";
    for(int i=0; i<100;i++)
       std::cout << x[i] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
   }
%}


%include "numpy.i"


%init %{
import_array();
 __call_at_begining();
%}

%inline %{
  void finalize(void) {
    __call_at_end();
  }
%}

// This is the SWIG magic:
%apply (double** ARGOUTVIEW_ARRAY1, int *DIM1) {(double** d, int* d_n)}
// Here's the Interface decalartion for Python:
void view_x(double** d, int* d_n); // SWIG declaration
void print_x();
```

I like [Cmake](http://www.cmake.org/), so here's a minimal `CMakeLists.txt` file for using SWIG (tested under Debian Sid), build with `cmake .` and `make`:

```
# This is a CMake example for Python
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

FIND_PACKAGE(SWIG REQUIRED)
INCLUDE(${SWIG_USE_FILE})

FIND_PACKAGE(PythonLibs)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_PATH})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} )
SET(CMAKE_SWIG_FLAGS "")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(tstI.i PROPERTIES CPLUSPLUS ON)
SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(tstI.i PROPERTIES SWIG_FLAGS "-includeall")
SWIG_ADD_MODULE(tstI python tstI.i ) 
SWIG_LINK_LIBRARIES(tstI ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

In the following a sample Python session using the wrapper:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import tstI # loads module
__call_at_begining() ...

In [3]: y = tstI.view_x() # get memory view

In [4]: y[:10]
Out[4]: array([  0.,  10.,  20.,  30.,  40.,  50.,  60.,  70.,  80.,  90.])

In [5]: y[:10] = np.zeros(10)

In [6]: tstI.print_x() # dump memory contents
x = 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170 180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 
270 280 290 300 310 320 330 340 350 360 370 380 390 400 410 420 430 440 450 460 470 480 490 
500 510 520 530 540 550 560 570 580 590 600 610 620 630 640 650 660 670 680 690 700 710 720 
730 740 750 760 770 780 790 800 810 820 830 840 850 860 870 880 890 900 910 920 930 940
950 960 970 980 990
```